# MVC - Como carregar uma página html de modelo, modifica-la e enviar por e-mail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, envio-de-email

Estou fazendo um formulário que envia um e-mail ao cliente, esse e-mail vem de um modelo dependendo do estágio do cliente. Ex: Estágio 01 envio o e-mail com a body vindo do modelo_01.html, se o cliente está no estágio 04, envio o e-mail com o modelo_04.html

*Estou fazendo de um formato que funciona, porém como MVC é novidade para mim, as vezes acho que estou fazendo na forma hardcore. As vezes existe um meio mais simples e desconheço.*

**Como estou fazendo:**
Dentro da view em questão crio um arquivo modelo_01.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
    <body>
        <p>Prezado Cliente [Nome_Cliente],</p>
        <p>Estamos lhe enviando o andamento do seu site conosco.</p>
        <p>Novo status atualizado em:</p>
        <p>   [Mostra_EP] </p>
        <p>[data]<p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Na controller chamei uma biblioteca que criei que faz o envio do email.
Primeiro faço a leitura por FileSystem

```
var conteudo = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Caminho);
```

Depois faço os replace dos campos [Nome_Cliente],[Mostra_EP],[data]

```
conteudo = conteudo.Replace("[Nome_Cliente]", cliente.Nome);
conteudo = couteudo.Replace("[data],DateTime.Now);
```

No [Mostra_EP] é um pouco mais complexo pois faço uma consulta no banco de dados e um foreach e vou montando um html.
Depois disso
Envio esse conteúdo em:

```
 objEmail.Body = conteudo;
```

Existe algo mais simples? tipo uma Partial que eu chamando ela ela já me retornaria um html já pronto (ela executa e retorna um html) pois a parte do [Mostra_EP] está ficando gigante e nem finalizei ainda.

Comment: Pesquise por "asp.net template engine".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu raciocínio é correto, você está fazendo muito hardcore.

Se você está utilizando Asp.net MVC (Suponho que também esteja usando Razor Views), você pode usar o recurso do razor para renderizar este html para você.

.cshtml file:

```
@model SuaModelClasse
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Prezado Cliente @model.NomeCliente,</p>
    <p>Estamos lhe enviando o andamento do seu site conosco.</p>
    <p>Novo status atualizado em:</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Itens)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Col1</td>
                <td>@item.Col2</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <p>@Model.Data<p>
</body>
</html>
```

Isso é um exemplo. Você pode usar todos os recursos do Razor Views. Depois renderize sua view em uma string e ponha a string no body do email.

Isso pode ser feito seguindo o que foi respondido [nesta pergunta.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759898/1233788)

Abaixo o código tirado da resposta citada acima:

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    ViewData.Model = model;

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines
            .FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);

        var viewContext = new ViewContext(
            ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);

        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```